# Primitive operation for nested for loop

Tags: algorithm

I am confused in how to calculate total number of primitive operation.
I did this by my own but this is not correct.

```
for (i: 1 to n) --------- n
    for (j: 1 to i) -------- n ( i - 1 )
        for (k: j to i) ---------------- n ( n - 1 ) * ( i - 1 )
            s= s + 1 ------------- n ( n - 1 ) * ( i )
```

Total Number of primitive operation for this code is **n + n(i - 1) + n (n-1)*(i-1) * n(n-1) * (i)**.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(sum(i-j%2B1+for+j+%3D+1..i)+for+i+%3D+1..n)

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate from inside out: 
Single execution of innermost for loop performs (i-j+1) primitive addition operations. But that's done for i times in the immediate outer loop leading to a count of (i-1+1) + (i-2+1) + .. + (i-i+1)=i*(i+1)/2 primitive operations so far. Now comes the outermost for loop that repeats everything for n times leading to a total count of (1/2)*(1*1+2*2+..+n * n) +(1/2)*(1+2+..+n)=(1/2)*(n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6+n*(n+1)/2)=(1/12)*(2*n^3+6*n^2+4*n)=O(n^3) primitive operations. The final count should only be a function of n and no other variables.